# Conditionally source a script in zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I currently source an initializations script in my `.zshrc`. Unfortunately this makes some modifications to my environment and `$PATH` I don't want, unless I'm in some specific directories.

Sure, I could compare the output of `pwd` with the current dir, but I would like to source if I'm in a specific directory **or** one of its subdirectories at any level.

And is there probably an entirely different solution to my problem?

Comment: So you want these modifications to be only present in some Terminal windows and not others? Because you can always change directory. Run a script that initiate that (including changing the prompt to warn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a child process just to run `pwd` is overkill. You find your current directory always stored in the variable `PWD`. This variable is maintained automatically by zsh.

You can find whether your working directory is in or below a certain directory `dir`  by

```
if [[ $PWD:A == $dir:A || $PWD:A == $dir:A/** ]]
then
  # I am in $dir or below it
  ...
fi
```

The `:A` takes care of the cases where one of the path components involved in the comparision happens to be a symlink. I'm not sure whether you will need this for `PWD`, but it does not harm using it.